# Configuring a repeater for a non-native vlan

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, vlan

I my office I have 3 Cisco Aironet 1130AG series access points. I want to setup a new access point as a repeater. So far I have configured it a repeater using [Cisco's website](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-4_3g_JA/configuration/guide/ios1243gjaconfigguide/s43hot.html). Also, I am configuring from Windows 7 OS using CLI. The three access points are configured as root access points. Each of these access points have two vlans that are `vlan 150` and `vlan 158`. `The vlan 150 is the native vlan`. The `vlan 150` is for internal users as it provides access to internal servers too. The `vlan 158` is for external users/guests just for using internet.

I want to configure the new access point as repeater for only the external users. Only 1 of the 3 Root Access Points will be its parent. Is it possible to do so, because I am having trouble in doing so.
My Repeater doesn't connect to the parent. Using many different Websites, I learned that the Option `infrastructure-ssid` should be enabled on Parent and Repeater, however, it does not seem to get along with my VLAN Configuration. It only allows me to enable the `infrastructure-ssid` option when my VLAN is off or on default and not 158. `infrastructure-ssid` command can only be applied on the native vlan. So, how can I make a repeater that provides access to the non-native vlan? Is there any work around?

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me what my mistake is or even provide an example configuration.
If neccessary, I can provide my Configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem. So here is my conclusion. You cannot create a repeater for a SSID which is not configured on a native vlan. Because to create a repeater you need to set the SSID as an infrastructure ssid using `infrastructure-ssid` command on the root access point as well as on the repeater device. This `infrastructure-ssid` command will only work if the SSID is configured on a native vlan on the root access point. Thats what I understood after experimenting on my Cisco Aironet 1130AG access point.